# What is the dual problem of a typical $L_1$ norm?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I was reading the [solutions](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf) of Pr. Boyd's optimisation book. In the solution set, for question 6.4 it is stated that the dual problem of the following problem:

$$\min {||Ax-b||_1} $$

is:

\begin{gather*}
\max  {\sum_{i=1}^m{b_i\lambda_i}} \\
\text{such that} \quad |\lambda_i| \le1, i=1, \ldots, m \\
\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i a_i = 0
\end{gather*}

The point is that I've tried to write the first problem as the second by employing conjugate, and I've verified the first and last lines of the second problem, but I really cannot figure out the second line of the second problem. I guess it may have a connection to the conjugate norm, but don't know how it may, and also I'm not sure. Does anyone have any opinion?

It's worth mentioning that the $\ell^1$ norm can easily be written using two dual $\lambda$s, but for this specific problem, another approach has been utilised using norm conjugate I believe.

Comment: I am a bit disappointed by the fact you explicitly asked about the conjugate approach, but then accepted an answer that does not use conjugates

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you for your provided answer, but the point was that I was trying to provide what I'd done till that time, and it was something which I thought was the solution. By the way, the middle lines of the accepted answer were exactly the solution I demanded. Notwithstanding this fact, I've already upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive the dual via linear programming.  Rewrite the primal problem as the following linear program, with dual variables in parentheses:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_i z_i \\
&\text{subject to} & z_i - \sum_j A_{i,j} x_j &\ge b_i &&(\alpha_i \ge 0)\\
& & z_i + \sum_j A_{i,j} x_j &\ge -b_i &&(\beta_i \ge 0)\\
& & x_j &\quad\text{ free} \\
& & z_i &\ge 0
\end{align}

The dual problem is then:
\begin{align}
&\text{maximize} &\sum_i b_i \alpha_i - \sum_i b_i \beta_i \\
&\text{subject to} & -\sum_i A_{i,j} \alpha_i + \sum_i A_{i,j} \beta_i &= 0 &&(\text{$x_j$ free})\\
& & \alpha_i + \beta_i &\le 1 &&(z_i \ge 0)\\
& & \alpha_i &\ge 0 \\
& & \beta_i &\ge 0
\end{align}

Now let $\lambda_i = \alpha_i - \beta_i$.  Because $\alpha_i \ge 0$ and $\beta_i \ge 0$, we have $|\lambda_i| \le \alpha_i + \beta_i$.

So the dual problem becomes:
\begin{align}
&\text{maximize} &\sum_i b_i \lambda_i \\
&\text{subject to} & \sum_i A_{i,j} \lambda_i &= 0 &&(\text{$x_j$ free})\\
& & |\lambda_i| &\le 1 &&(z_i \ge 0)\\
& & \lambda_i &\quad \text{ free}
\end{align}

---

Alternatively, start with the dual problem as the linear program:
\begin{align}
&\text{maximize} &\sum_i b_i \lambda_i \\
&\text{subject to} & \sum_i A_{i,j} \lambda_i &= 0 &&(\text{$x_j$ free})\\
& & -\lambda_i &\le 1 &&(u_i \ge 0)\\
& & \lambda_i &\le 1 &&(v_i \ge 0)\\
& & \lambda_i &\quad \text{ free}
\end{align}

The dual of the dual is:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_i (u_i+v_i) \\
&\text{subject to} & \sum_j A_{i,j} x_j -u_i+v_i &= b_i &&(\text{$\lambda_i$ free})\\
& & x_j &\quad \text{ free} \\
& & u_i &\ge 0 \\
& & v_i &\ge 0
\end{align}

And this is the other well-known LP formulation for minimizing $||Ax-b||_1$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this line Now let $\lambda =\alpha_i - \beta_i$ ...

Comment: It is just a change of variables.  A typical way to represent a free variable $y$ is as a difference of nonnegative variables: $y=y^+-y^-$, where $y^+=\max(y,0)$ is the "positive part" of $y$ and $y^-=\max(-y,0)$ is the "negative part" of $y$.  Note that $y^+ \cdot y^- = 0$ and $|y| = y^+ +y^-$.

Comment: Sorry, I was using my phone and couldn't elaborate. I'm not familiar with the concept you've referred to, but after searching I've figured out the meaning of free variable. The point here is that you've referred, $\lambda_i = \alpha_i - \beta_i$ which are two distinct variables which are not necessarily the maximum of a same variable. I have a simple question. I've realised almost everything you've mentioned, but cannot understand why $\lambda_i = \alpha_i - \beta_i$ has led to  $|λi|=αi+βi$. Would you mind telling me this?

Comment: It should have been $\le$ instead of $=$.  I corrected it just now.

Comment: thank you and sorry for my late response.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the conjugate approach. The problem is:

$$\min_{x,y} \left\{  ||y||_1 : y = Ax-b  \right\}$$
The Lagrangian is:
$$L(x,y,\lambda) = ||y||_1+\lambda^T(y-Ax+b)$$
so the dual is
\begin{align}
& \max_{\lambda} \min_{x,y} \left\{ ||y||_1+\lambda^T(y-Ax+b) \right\} \\
= &\max_{\lambda} \left\{ b^T\lambda + \min_x (A^T\lambda)^Tx -\max_y (-\lambda)^Ty - ||y||_1 \right\} \\
= &\max_{\lambda} \left\{ b^T\lambda : A^T\lambda = 0, ||\lambda||_{\infty} \leq 1 \right\}
\end{align}
In the last step I used the conjugate of the $1$-norm. The function value of the conjugate is 0 if the dual norm (so the $\infty$-norm) of $-\lambda$ is at most $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a Lagrangian based approach.

Starting from the original problem:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}& ||Ax-b||_1 
\end{align}

We can reformulate this as a constrained optimization problem:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} & ||y||_1 \\
&\text{subject to} & Ax-b =y
\end{align}

We can then form this problem's Lagrangian:
$$L(x, y, \lambda)= ||y||_1 + \lambda^\top (y - Ax + b)$$

The Lagrange dual function is:

$$g(\lambda) = \inf_{x, y} L(x, y, \lambda)$$

The dual problem is to maximize $g(\lambda)$. For this problem, we can constrain $\lambda$ so that $g(\lambda) > -\infty$.

Note that if $\lambda^T A \neq 0$ then it is easy to see $g(\lambda) = -\infty$ (set $x = cA^\top \lambda$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $c \to \infty$).

We claim if any $|\lambda_i| > 1$ then $g(\lambda) = -\infty$. To see this, set $y = ce_i$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x = 0$. Then $L(x, y, \lambda) = |c| + \lambda_i c + \lambda^\top b$. If $\lambda_i > 1$, then $L(x, y, \lambda) \to -\infty$ as $c \to -\infty$ and if $\lambda_i < -1$ then $L(x, y, \lambda) \to -\infty$ as $c \to \infty$.

Thus, the dual problem is:

\begin{align}
&\text{maximize} & g(\lambda) \\
&\text{subject to} & \lambda^\top A = 0 \\
& & |\lambda_i| \leq 1 \text{ for } i = 1, ..., m
\end{align}

Finally, we claim $g(\lambda) = \lambda^\top b$ when $\lambda$ lies in the constraint set above. It is obvious that if $\lambda^\top A = 0$ then:
$$L(x, y, \lambda) = ||y||_1 + \lambda^\top y + \lambda^\top b =  \left[\sum_{i=1}^m |y_i| + \lambda_i y_i\right] + \lambda^\top b$$

For $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$, we have:
\begin{align*}
|\lambda_i| \leq 1 &\implies -|\lambda_i| \geq -1 \\
&\implies -|\lambda_i||y_i| \geq -|y_i| \\
&\implies |y_i|-|\lambda_i||y_i| \geq 0 \\
&\implies |y_i| + \lambda_i y_i \geq 0
\end{align*}

Thus $L(x, y, \lambda) \geq \lambda^\top b$ for all $x, y$ given that $\lambda$ lies in the constraint set. But this lower bound is achieved by setting $x = 0$ and $y= 0$. Hence, $g(\lambda) = \lambda^\top b$ for $\lambda$ in the constraint set.

The final dual problem is:
\begin{align}
&\text{maximize} & \lambda^\top b \\
&\text{subject to} & \lambda^\top A = 0 \\
& & |\lambda_i| \leq 1 \text{ for } i = 1, ..., m
\end{align}